# How to use chart with a Wagtail CMS

Tags: python, django, charts, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I need to include custom charts to a streamfield function, as you can find [with Tauchart](https://api.taucharts.com/tutorials/5min.html).

But how is it possible to a user to modify the data from the wagtail admin? I have absolutely no idea on how I can do this.

I'm pondering about a form but it's possible to add a form to a streamfield ? I think yes, I can do it with a link to an existing form. But that seems hard to make and not a good idea.

What do you think about?
What is the best practice for you ?

Do you have any examples of Taucharts integration into a CMS?

Comment: A similar project I did was Wagtail Code Block. In it, I use an HTML textarea to hold code, and create a "preview area" of what the code will look like highlighted. You could do something similar and have it build the JSON the chart needs. Have a look: https://github.com/FlipperPA/wagtailcodeblock

Comment: You should figure out how you like to input your data (file field, text area, fixed set of input fields, dynamic set of input fields). Only after you can store your data in the CMS you can think of ways to output it. Tauchart accepts json.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom block inside blocks.py, for example LineChartBlock() that references a template called line_chart.html. You'll need to import your custom block into your models.py file to add it to your StreamField. Then a user on the CMS admin side can enter values and save them as parameters. Which you can then pass into the template as dynamic JavaScript variables, which you can use to create your custom chart. Here's a super rough idea...

So blocks.py would look like this:

```
from wagtail.core import blocks

class LineChartBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    title = blocks.CharBlock()
    x = blocks.DecimalBlock()
    y = blocks.DecimalBlock()
    data = JSONField()

    class Meta:
        template = 'blocks/line_chart.html'
```

Your models.py:

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    body = StreamField([
        ('paragraph', RichTextBlock()),
        ('line_chart', LineChartBlock()),
    ])
```

Your template:

```
<script>
    const title = "{{ title }}";
    const x = "{{ x }}";
    const y = "{{ y }}";
    const data = "{{ data }}";

    makeChartWizardry = () => {
       doStuff;
    }

</script>

<section>
    <div id="chart"></div>
</section>
```